# Incompatible return type (Java)

Tags: java, type-parameter

```
public class Example<T extends A & B>  {
}

interface A{
    void remove(); // removes one element if present
}

interface B{
    int remove(); // removes all element and returns the count
}
```

**This is just the sample code.** It shows error

> Error:(1, 22) java: types B and A are incompatible;
> both define remove(), but with unrelated return types

How to correct it?

Comment: I agree with the compiler here :) What do you expect Java to do if you call `remove` on a variable of type `T`? Which `remove` will it call?

Comment: just change your methods name

Comment: @NitinSinghal agreed but if its inbuilt classes like Map and List

Comment: @vikalprusia How would you implement the `remove()` method when the return type has to be `int` and `void` at the same time (as defined by the different interfaces)?

Comment: Are you saying that you are doing `T extends Map & List`? Why does it make sense to do that?

Comment: @Sweeper it really don't make sense but my instructor told me that it can extend interface and i randomly tried and landed here

Comment: Well, then the solution here is pretty obvious - _Don't write code that doesn't make sense_. :) Don't use `Map & List`, try something else.

Comment: @Sweeper can you please post a answer so i can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

From @Sweeper comments I am able to figure out <T extends A & B> means the class should implement both interface A&B while creating objects of Example class which in my case is not possible as both have same method name so error was reasonable so the implementing class will also produce an error.

Answer (score -1):

1. you have to use `implements` instead of `extends` because A and B are interfaces .
2. you have to override the methods of A and B

   ```
    public class T implements A , B  {
        public T(){
            super();
        }
        @Override
        public void remove1(){
        }
        @Override
        public int remove2(){
            return 0;
        }
    }

    interface A{
         void remove1(); // removes one element if present
    }

    interface B{
        int remove2(); // removes all element and returns the count
    }
   ```

Comment: You just change the name of the interface-methods and did not provide any description of your answer. Please review your answer and add more details about what and why the questioner should do this.